# Grub Customizer Error on startup

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I cant start Grub Customizer in ubuntu 12.04 after updating the kernel:

```
exception '15AssertException'
with message 'found unexpected file on path: /etc/grub.d/10_linux'
in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-3.0.2/src/Model/ListCfg.cpp:916
```

Also update-grub command shows two identical kernels:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sdb1
```

**Solution found: i removed all files in /etc/grub.d/ starting with DS_ and used update-grab again**

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+bug/1059506 (nothing else pops up on goolge :D )